# Two different ASP.Net Membership providers on the same web-solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have built two websites, both of them use a custom membership provider I have written myself.

One of these sites is already a long time online and runs fine. Now I have installed the other site on the same webserver in the same Web as a different application. Also have I given a seperate ApplicationPool for each solution.

If now the client logs on to one site, he looses the session on the other and vice versa. It's not possible to be loged on on both sites together. All the rest works fine.

What is the connection between the two sites. Is it necessary to change something in my membership providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you change the session cookie name for each application:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9

Update:
Right answer was to change the form name. See comments below.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, however I allready tried this in ISS-Management console. Sadly, it has not helped.

Comment: And the form name?
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".Authentication" loginUrl="../Login.aspx" protection="None" timeout="43200" path="/">

I had the opposite issue a while ago, I needed too applications to run under the same session and authentication.
</forms>

Comment: I have a new post concerning the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728036/asp-net-remember-me-not-working-anymore-with-forms-authentication Maybe you know a solution?